# Error: Reference.update failed: First argument contains an invalid key

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I getting this error on firebase (working with vue.js):

It all goes well the first time and I can run the following function as many times as I want.

```
addSpace: function (newSpace) { 
  let userId = firebaseApp.auth().currentUser.uid;  
  const key = spacesRef.push().key;  // creating the key once
  console.log(key); 
  spacesRef.child(key).update(this.newSpace); }
```

However if when I run another function (see the function bellow AddDept) the addSpace function throws an error:

```
addDept: function(space, dept, newDept, event) {
  this.newSpace = space;//get current space
  const deptKey = deptsRef.push().key; // create Dept Key
  let spaceKey = space['.key']; 
  console.log(spaceKey)
  var deptNode = spacesRef.child(spaceKey).child("hasDepts"); 
  deptNode.child(deptKey).set(true);
  deptsRef.child(deptKey).set(this.newDept);
  deptsRef.child(deptKey).child("spaceName").set(space.name);
  deptsRef.child(deptKey).child("spaceKey").set(spaceKey);
  this.newDept.name = '';
  this.newDept.comments = '';
  this.newSpaceKey= '';
  },
```

What the heck is happening here?

```
Error: Reference.update failed: First argument contains an invalid key 
 (.key) in path /.key. Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"
```

I have console.logged all arguments, and they seem sane. I have also tried stringifiying the arguments with no success.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: I thinking it is saying `'.key'` <-- it does not like the `.`

Comment: Maybe this will help. https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/458

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to
     **delete space['.key'];** to the addDept function

Thanks @skribe